# Using systemd-timesync on a read-only / filesystem

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, readonly, systemd-timesyncd

I'm trying to set-up a Raspberry Pi with read-only filesystems.  The base image is the debian buster lite raspbian image.
Most stuff is working, e.g. had to do simple fixes like:

```bsh
mv /etc/resolv.conf /var/run/resolv.conf && ln -s /var/run/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Similar for dhcp and a few other services

However, there is one service that I would like to get working, that refuses to work like this: systemd-timesync.

Here's what I did and what happens.systemd-timesync
I created a directory /run/systemd-timesync, owned by user systemd-timesync:systemd-timesync
Then created a symlink /var/lib/systemd/timesync -> /run/systemd-timesync

```
root@raspberrypi:/var/lib/systemd # ls -l /var/lib/systemd/timesync
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Dec 25 14:48 /var/lib/systemd/timesync -> /run/systemd-timesync

root@raspberrypi:/var/lib/systemd # ls -l /run/systemd-timesync/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 systemd-timesync systemd-timesync 0 Dec 25 15:02 clock
```

The relevant part of the systemd unit file:

```
...
[Service]
User=systemd-timesync
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_SYS_TIME
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SYS_TIME
WorkingDirectory=/run/systemd-timesync
Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug
ExecStartPre=/bin/pwd
ExecStart=!!/lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
...
RuntimeDirectory=systemd/timesync
StateDirectory=systemd/timesync
...
```

Note that I added a ExecStartPre=/bin/pwd which should just output the current working directory to the journal.

Now if I start the systemd-timesync with / mounted as read-only, this is what happens

```
root@raspberrypi:/var/lib/systemd # systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd.service && systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl start systemd-timesyncd.service
Job for systemd-timesyncd.service failed because of unavailable resources or another system error.
See "systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The output of journalctl

```
Dec 25 15:34:10 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Trying to enqueue job systemd-timesyncd.service/stop/replace
Dec 25 15:34:10 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Installed new job systemd-timesyncd.service/stop as 1214
Dec 25 15:34:10 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Enqueued job systemd-timesyncd.service/stop as 1214
Dec 25 15:34:10 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Job 1214 systemd-timesyncd.service/stop finished, result=done
Dec 25 15:34:10 raspberrypi systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service:36: Failed to parse system call, ignoring: io_pgetevents
Dec 25 15:34:10 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Changed dead -> failed
Dec 25 15:34:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Trying to enqueue job systemd-timesyncd.service/start/replace
Dec 25 15:34:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Installed new job systemd-timesyncd.service/start as 1215
Dec 25 15:34:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Enqueued job systemd-timesyncd.service/start as 1215
Dec 25 15:34:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/VBoxService succeeded.
Dec 25 15:34:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/chronyd succeeded.
Dec 25 15:34:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/openntpd succeeded.
Dec 25 15:34:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/ntpd succeeded.
Dec 25 15:34:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: ConditionVirtualization=!container succeeded.
Dec 25 15:34:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: ConditionCapability=CAP_SYS_TIME succeeded.
Dec 25 15:34:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Failed to run 'start-pre' task: Read-only file system
Dec 25 15:34:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Dec 25 15:34:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Job 1215 systemd-timesyncd.service/start finished, result=failed
Dec 25 15:34:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
```

Clearly the /bin/pwd from ExecStartPre fails because of the read-only filesystem.  I do not understand this, and don't know how to work around it.  If I remove the ExecStartPre the same happens with the ExecStart command.

When I however do,

```bsh
mount -o remount,rw /
```

and subsequently

```
root@raspberrypi:/var/lib/systemd # systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd.service && systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl start systemd-timesyncd.service
```

all works fine, including the pwd output to the journal.

Similarly when I start

```
root@raspberrypi:/var/lib/systemd # /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
Synchronized to time server for the first time 84.199.86.247:123 (0.debian.pool.ntp.org).
```

all works fine.

So far, my conclusion seems to be that systemd REQUIRES write-access somewhere to start any command in ExecStartPre or ExecStart.

Any ideas on how I can achieve my original goal of having the raspberry update it's time settings?

Note: it may be related to the lines StateDirectory, RuntimeDirectory in the unit file.

Answer (score 1):

That solved the problem on DietPi for me:

- /run is mounted as tmpfs
- Create a softlink for the StateDirectory under /var/lib:

  `ln -s /run /var/lib/run`
- disable PrivateTmp

  `#PrivateTmp=yes`
- changing StateDirectory to tmpfs:

  `StateDirectory=run/timesync`

RuntimeDirectory is absolute to /run, wich already is a tmpfs, so this doesn't need to be changed

Comment: This is more or less equivalent to `StateDirectory=`, because the directory used by systemd-timesyncd is [hardcoded](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/df8fd03a7dcf2f06cd9e2ee3eed60c3a83b43ccc/src/timesync/timesyncd.c#L24).

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of tinkering around, it turns out that commenting out the following 2 lines in the [Unit] section is enough:

```
#CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SYS_TIME
#PrivateTmp=yes
```

These turn out to be the only 2 lines that require commenting out, to have it all working on a read-only / filesystem.

It's beyond me why uncommenting any of these 2 lines breaks systemd-timesync working on a read-only filesystem.  I would expect PrivateTmp=yes to create a private tmpfs mounted on the private /tmp for that process, but apparently not.  May be a bug in systemd then.

Comment: The reason my service didn't work, is because my OS uses `/run/tmpfiles.d` instead of `/tmp`, but apparently systemd still is configured to use `/tmp`. Therefore, this solved it for me: `ln -s /run/tmpfiles.d /tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use `overlayfs` to make read only (but fake writable) the / filesystem. This will prevent some systemd services fails.

You can do this using `raspi-config` script in `4 Performance Options` > `P3 Overlay File System`

Then the FS will be read only but fake writable (all changes will be lost at shutdown or reboot).

You can read the [raspi-config](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config) script for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Just setting `StateDirectory=` worked for me. Instead of editing system files, you can put a couple of lines in e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d/local-allow-readonly.conf`:

```
[Service]
StateDirectory=
```

The directory/file path are hardcoded in [timesyncd.c](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/df8fd03a7dcf2f06cd9e2ee3eed60c3a83b43ccc/src/timesync/timesyncd.c#L24), so it doesn't change much, except `User=systemd-timesync` means that systemd-timesyncd can't create directory itself. So,

- If you do this before systemd-timesync first runs (e.g. in an initial setup script), the directory (and clock file) will never be created.
- If you do this after the directory has been created, the clock file can be updated when the filesystem is mounted read-write.

(If you're wondering where the error comes from, I'm guessing it's the [attempt to chmod](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/e65357b6585629ee2138e53d02face3914621a2e/src/core/execute.c#L2447) which fails with EROFS even if the mode is already set to the desired mode. It seems unrelated to `PrivateTmp` and `CapabilityBoundingSet`.)